# File Upload Issues in Autodesk Platform Services

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to upload a file (a .png as a test) directly to the ACC cloud using the [Object API](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/b39cc7cefbe71c96051285f0ac25445d85a5e2a6/docs/ObjectsApi.md#forgesdkobjectsapi). With the following code I get a 200 response back. But I cannot see the uploaded file in the ACC folder. What am I doing wrong?

```
const { bucketKey, objectKey } = req.body;
const fileContent = await fs.readFile("file.png");
const response = await new APS.ObjectsApi().uploadResources(
  bucketKey,
  [
    {
      objectKey: objectKey,
      data: fileContent,
    },
  ],
  {},
  internalAuthClient,
  req.internalOAuthToken
);
```

Also, the API documentation seems a bit ambiguous. According to the [Object API](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/b39cc7cefbe71c96051285f0ac25445d85a5e2a6/docs/ObjectsApi.md#forgesdkobjectsapi), there is a method called [`uploadObject`](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/b39cc7cefbe71c96051285f0ac25445d85a5e2a6/docs/ObjectsApi.md#uploadobject), but looking at the [Source Code](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/b39cc7cefbe71c96051285f0ac25445d85a5e2a6/src/api/ObjectsApi.js#L81), this method is deprecated. On the other hand, the [`uploadResources`](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/b39cc7cefbe71c96051285f0ac25445d85a5e2a6/src/api/ObjectsApi.js#L1362C14-L1362C14) method is not mentioned in the [Object API](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/b39cc7cefbe71c96051285f0ac25445d85a5e2a6/docs/ObjectsApi.md#forgesdkobjectsapi) documentation. So I am not sure if I am using the method correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a file to ACC Docs, there are some additional steps to create a new version to get it listed in the folder. Here are the steps you can refer https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/ .

About the upload code, you can reference https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-create-revit-family/blob/master/routes/da4revit.js#L233 to post an item or a new version.

Comment: Perfect! The second link was the missing piece. Thank you very much.